# TypeError: Cannot call method ‘onReady’ of null Ionic.io

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, ionic-framework

i'm working on a app that will integrate the ionic push notification , so i started with demo provided , but when i try to register for the push i get this error :

"TypeError: Cannot call method 'onReady' of null
I/chromium(21359): at new e (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic-platform-web-client/dist/ionic.io.bundle.min.js:2:30167)

here is my controller code

```
  var push = new Ionic.Push({
    "debug": true
  });

  push.register(function(token) {
    console.log("Device token:",token.token);
    push.addTokenToUser(user);
    user.save();
  });
```

my App.js module

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic',
                       'ionic.service.core',
                       'ionic.service.push',
                       'ionic.service.deploy',
                       'ngCordova',
                       'angular-md5',
                       'ionic.service.analytics', 
                       'starter.controllers',
                       'starter.services',
                       'starter.config',
                       'toaster', 
                       'ngAnimate',
                       'angularMoment',
                       'ngStorage',
                       'angular-svg-round-progress',
                       'ionic-cache-src'])
```

can any one help me ??
thanks

Comment: show your app.js where you have initialized anugular module

Comment: check my Update . thanks